# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" by passing the data to the Vuex-state

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am fetching the data from a MongoDB through sending `GET` requests to my API. Then I loop through the `response.data` and in each `response.data` through its properties to push the data which I need to `nextArray`. And this `nextArray` should be passed to the `schedulingQuality`-state in the Vuex. That's how it looks like:

```js
methods: {
    ...mapActions(
      ['setSchedulingQuality']
  ),
    get_data() {
    const nextArray = [];
      for(let i in this.SelectedtValues) {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getexp/'+this.SelectedtValues[i])
    .then(res => {
       for(let n in res.data) {
         nextArray.push(res.data[n].output)
        }
      }
   )}
console.log(nextArray);
      },
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(
    ['schedulingQuality','selectedValues']
  ),
    SelectedtValues() {
    return this.$store.getters.selectedValues;
    } ,
     schedulingQuality() {
    return this.schedulingQuality;
    }
  }
```

When I'm printing out the `nextArray` then it seems to be ok. I'm getting a `[]` on the console and after I click on it the correct content appears with a small `i` icon which tells: "`Value below was evaluated just now`". However I am not able to print out the items of this Array separately, each of them has a value of `undefined`, when I try that.
But my main problem is that it throws an `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error, when I'm trying to pass it to my Vuex-state in the code above befor printing out, like:

```js
this.setSchedulingQuality(nextArray)
```

Here is my Vuex-code:

```js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      schedulingQuality: [],
    },
    mutations: {
      SchedulingQuality(state, payload) {
        state.schedulingQuality = payload;
      }
    },
    actions: {
      setSchedulingQuality({commit}, payload){
          commit('SchedulingQuality',payload)
      }
    },
    getters: {
      schedulingQuality(state) {
        return state.schedulingQuality;
      }
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

My questions are:

- Why it is not possible to print out the Array items separately?
- Why I'am getting this error
- And how can I fix it?
  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios` call is asynchronous. At the time you call `console.log(nextArray)`, axios function is not finished yet. That's why you got empty array.

You call multiple api asynchronously, I suggest you check out [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
get_data() {
    const nextArray = [];
    Promise.all(this.SelectedtValues.map(value => {
        return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getexp/' + value)
    })).then(results => {
        results.map(res => {
        for(let n in res.data) {
            nextArray.push(res.data[n].output)
            }
        })
        console.log(nextArray);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: And you have just saved my day one more time Ittus. Thank you.